# App is not available on Google Play, but device is on supported devices list

Tags: android, google-play, device, compatibility

For some reason, my app in Google Play Store is not available for Samsung A50 (and maybe some other devices?), despite the thing that device is on the list of supported devices. App is available for all sort of other devices.

I can install app on A50 manually (as APK), and it works without problems.

A50 is not on the list of excluded devices.

Can you help me how to solve this problem, and to have it available on A50?

App use only internet connection (and have proper permission), so I don't think it is some permission related problem.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Hi, Can you share your AndroidManifest.xml file? maybe you used same of hardware component like STEP_SENSOR

Answer (score 0):

It might be a problem with the application size,if you create an app that say "hello world" and nothing else then it will work,here is a response from google developer:

> Thank you for your note. Currently the maximum file size limit for an app upload to Google Play is approximately 50 MB.
> However, some devices may have smaller than 50 MB cache partition making the app unavailable for users to download. For example, some of HTC Wildfire devices are known for having 35-40 MB cache partitions. If Google Play is able to identify such device that doesn't have cache large enough to store the app, it may filter it from appearing for the user.

Comment: No, there is more that 50% of free space on device. And app is small and simple, it is about 3MB of size.